# How to use wildcard paths with Ansible `find` module?

Tags: ansible, find, wildcard, glob

I am trying to remove leftover files from several directories *on a remote host* using Ansible playbook.

```
/some_dir
├── dir_1
│   └── file_A
├── dir_2
│   └── file_B
└── dir_3
    └── file_C
```

If I used shell script, for example, I would go with simple glob like `rm -rf /some_dir/dir_*/file_*`, it is specific enough.  I would like to stick to best Ansible practices™ though, so I decided to go with combination of [`find`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html) and [`file`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html) modules.

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: Find files to remove by patterns
    find:
      paths: "/some_dir/dir_*/"
      patterns: "file_*"
```

However, wildcards don't seem to work in `find`'s `paths`, they are treated as literal.

Is there any way to work around these limitations?

Notes:

1. I understand that I could search for `file_[A-Z]` in `some_dir` recursively, but then it might catch `/some_dir/very_important_stuff/file_Q` (I will go with that solution, if all else fails)
2. I can use shell commands or scripts to use shell expansion on remote host, then parse its stdout to get list of files, but it sounds like an error-prone hack
3. In this particular case I can run two `find` tasks: find all the `dir_*` in `some_dir`, then use them as a list of `paths` to find `file_*`s, but since this task(s) a part of a bigger real playbook, it'll be too complicated to use for paths with wildcards in arbitrary positions (`/some_dir/dir_*/other/cruft/subdirs/*.cache`).

Answer (score 2):

Not directly possible with ansible. You have to go with a `shell` command:

```
---
- name: TEST
  hosts: host1
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
  - name: shell
    shell: "ls -1 /some_dir/dir_*/*"
    register: result

  - name: debug
    debug:
      var: result.stdout
```

Comment: But `fileglob` expands on a local host, while I need that to happen on a remote one.

Comment: Ah ok, I missed that. So far as I know, you will have to go with two tasks or use a `command`.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but as I've mentioned in p.2 of my _Notes_, this is too much of a hack for my liking.  As Rule 34 states, _"Thou shalt not parse `ls` output_"

Comment: Hmmm, i'm at work so googling Rule 34 Ansible seems a bit risky ;)